# Xamarin forms toolbar items not displaying on view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a number of view pages that all inherit from ContentPage. The first page that is called
from the app.cs displays the icon in the toolbar correctly. The second page (TodoItemView) does not display an icon at all (the same code is used). Is there something that I need to do to initialize the toolbar for the second view?

thanks in advance.

```
This page is called by the following code:

      var todoList = new TodoListView();
      return new NavigationPage(todoList);

Th page is called by the following code:

      var todoList = new TodoListView();
      return new NavigationPage(todoList);




// Works shows refresh icon
public class TodoListView : ContentPage
    {
        public TodoListView ()
        {
            Title = "Social Events";

            // Display the refresh icon
            var toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem ("Refresh", "refresh.png", ()=>{
            }, 0, 0);
            ToolbarItems.Add (toolbarItem);

            var list = new ListView ();
            var viewModel = new TodoListViewModel ();
            list.ItemsSource = viewModel.TodoList;

            var cell = new DataTemplate (typeof(AspectImageCell));
            cell.SetBinding (TextCell.TextProperty, "Name");
            cell.SetBinding (TextCell.DetailProperty, "Details");
            cell.SetBinding (ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "Image");
            list.ItemTemplate = cell;
            list.ItemTapped += (sender, args) => {


                Navigation.PushAsync (new NavigationPage(new TodoItemView ()));

                // Reset the selected item
                list.SelectedItem = null;
            };

            Content = list;
        }
    }

// Does not work, does not show icon
public class TodoItemView : ContentPage
    {
        public TodoItemView ()
        {
            Title = "Todo item";

            var toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem ("Send", "send.png", ()=>{

                // email todo item

            }, 0, 0);
            ToolbarItems.Add (toolbarItem);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your ToolbarItems will not show if your app does not have a Toolbar. The simplest way to add one is to wrap your page in a `NavigationPage`

```
public static Page GetMainPage ()
{   
    return new NavigationPage(new SamplePage ());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create a NavigationPage once per navigation stack.  When you push TodoItemView, do this instead:

```
list.ItemTapped += (sender, args) => {
  Navigation.PushAsync (new TodoItemView ());
  // Reset the selected item
  list.SelectedItem = null;
};
```

TodoItemView will be pushed onto the navigation stack that is already contained within the first NavigationPage.  Eliminating the extra NavigationPage will probably fix your missing toolbar item too.  If it does not, also verify that the toolbar icon you specify is valid.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. Still the same problem. I verified the icon does exists. I also tried using the icon that worked on the first view. Still no luck.

Comment: I have found, if I create a toolbar item for the TodoListView, it is displayed on every view in the application i.e it is appearing on the TodoItemView as well

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to add one is to wrap your page in a `NavigationPage` object, and then call it like this:

```
var testPage = new NavigationPage(new TestPage());
Navigation.PushAsync(testPage);
```